# Creating Objects from input file

Tags: class, object, arraylist

I'm trying to somehow create objects by reading from a text file. However, I seem to be doing something wrong, and I can't put my finger on it.

Main:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Project2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner((new File("Project2DataFile.txt")));
    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    ArrayList<BaseballPlayer> myplayer = new ArrayList<BaseballPlayer>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        for(int cnt = 0; cnt < 4; cnt++){
            BaseballPlayer player = new BaseballPlayer();
            if( player.batavg < 0 || player.batavg > 100 ){throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Illegal Batting Avg");}
            player.pnumber = sc.nextInt();
            player.lastname = sc.next();
            player.firstname = sc.next();
            player.batavg = sc.nextFloat(); 
        }
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println(myplayer);

}
```

Class:

```
public class BaseballPlayer {

        public static int pnumber; // player number
        public static String lastname; // player's last name
        public static String firstname; // player's first name
        public static float batavg; // player's batting average
    }
```

And I might as well put the text file in there too:

```
48,deGrom,Jacob,.120
58,Mejia,Jenry,.140
49,Niese,Jon,.091
7,d'Arnaud,Travis,.324
21,Duda,Lucas,.237
4,Flores,Wilmner,.268
11,Tejada,Ruben,.345
5,Wright,David,.289
3,Granderson,Curtis,.327
12,Lagares,Juan,.298
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `static` incorrectly. `static` is for members shared by **all** instances of a class, so you should not use it in `BaseballPlayer`. To fix the problem, you need to remove all `static`s in `BaseballPlayer`.